# Previous closest date from array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

```
var dateArray = ['11/01/2020', '10/01/2020', '09/01/2020', '07/01/2020', '06/01/2020']
```

If I have a date `08/01/2020`, then I need to find its previous closest date in the array which is `07/01/2020`. I am omitting the time but that will also be part of the date.

Comment: Please add the JS you've written to the question so we can help you debug it

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you already tried, and give a specific problem description along with it. This site is not a code-writing service, so you need to show some initial effort at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dateArray = ['11/01/2020', '10/01/2020', '09/01/2020', '07/01/2020', '06/01/2020']

let date = '08/01/2020'

function findClosestPrevDate(arr,target){
    let targetDate = new Date(target);
    let previousDates = arr.filter(e => ( targetDate  - new Date(e)) > 0)
    let sortedPreviousDates =  previousDates.filter((a,b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
    return sortedPreviousDates[0] || null
}

let r1 = findClosestPrevDate(dateArray,"08/01/2020")
console.log(r1)

let r2 = findClosestPrevDate(dateArray,"10/01/2020")
console.log(r2)
```

Comment: Alan, can we return index instead of actual object?

Comment: yes you can `return arr.indexOf(sortedPreviousDates[0])`